# How to send javascript variable to a python script file

Tags: javascript, python

I am using this Html Geolocation Javascript code

```
window.onload = getLocation();
      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
          x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
      }

    
      function showPosition(position) {
        return position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude
        }
      showPosition();
```

I want the latitude and longitude values to be passed to another python script without using FLASK. I am already running django and am looking to run a python script based on these values in background

Comment: try to use ajax

Comment: *"without using FLASK"* You can freely choose your framework but a web application and an HTTP call is the way to go

Comment: how to use ajax?